# Trying to add an achievement to a user but I get an error saying the achievement has og:type of 'website'

Tags: facebook-opengraph, achievements

I've created and achievement:
https://graph.facebook.com/10150491734196645
It seems to be correct and there it says it is an achievement...
However when I try to add this achievement to an user i get the following error:

> facebook.GraphAPIError: (#3502) Object at URL 10150491734196645 has
>   og:type of 'website'. The property 'achievement' requires an object of
>   og:type 'game.achievement'.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like is an error form FB, the og: properties have to be defined by the webpage FB visits. Probably you should create a middle-step and reproduce the data that is provided at https://graph.facebook.com/10150491734196645 in your server with that og:type 'game.achievement' type defined.

Answer (score 0):

It was a stupid mistake, was passing the id of the achievement instead of the url!

Answer (score 0):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/10150491734196645?&access_token=*******************
```

Create an access_token and use this.

For access_token;

https://smashballoon.com/custom-facebook-feed/access-token/